# Ubuntu 18,04 crashes after logging in

Tags: login-screen

Not only me, but there are many users on my PC, so switching users is quite common operation. I have a bug since the installation of 18.04? that after entering the password ubuntu completely crashes(stops answering any command, even when I try to use console mode) Black screen. The only way to get back - hard reset. What may cause this issue?

Comment: Have you updated your system since installation of 18.04? Have you checked if there are anything in the log files indicating what crashed your system? /var/log/messages and /var/log/dmesg might be good places to look.

Comment: Log in at the console and move Your home directory and make a new one then try again - good luck

Comment: ```Sep 12 12:53:46 mlstation gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=justm
Sep 12 12:53:50 mlstation gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Sep 12 12:55:36 mlstation systemd-logind[949]: New seat seat0.
```
this is info from auth.log

Comment: gnome-shell[6092]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: asse
rtion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed